# EasyMock and methods returning a generic class

Tags: java, junit, tdd, powermock, easymock

Just wondering how do you mock a return object of type Class from a method using EasyMock or PowerMock?

I am trying to mock the return type of this interface method

```
Class<T> getRootBeanClass();
```

I tried the following but with no joy

```
EasyMock.expect(mockViolation.getRootBeanClass()).andReturn(EasyMock.anyObject());
```

I get this error message

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: matcher calls were used outside expectations
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Just for the record: you might want to delete old comments that are no longer required ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`anyObject()` is an **argument** matcher.

You use it so that EasyMock can *distinguish* between different mocking specifications that you put up. Like:

```
EasyMock.expect(mock.foo(eq("A"), anyObject()).andReturn(resultForA);
```

versus

```
EasyMock.expect(mock.foo(eq("B"), anyObject()).andReturn(resultForB);
```

The object that you **return** must be a *real* existing object (which can be either mocked, or not mocked). But `anyObject()` does not create an object for you!

EasyMock can't generate generics for you - so would need a cast, something like:

```
Class<Foo> foo = (Class<Foo>) mock(Class.class)
```

But this doesn't work in this case - as java.lang.Class is final! And EasyMock can't mock final classes! You need PowerMock for that - or (my recommendation) the latest version of Mockito.

In case you go for Mockito: please read their documentation - as you have to *enable* mocking of final classes - it is an experimental feature as of now.